# No se abre aplicación .exe creado con PyInstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

Revisé las entradas y no encontré una respuesta a este problema.
Genero el ejecutable de windows con PyInstaller. Ingreso a la carpeta dist/main abro el archivo main.exe y se abre la consola negra y se cierra.
Sin embargo, desde la consola puedo ejecutarlo correctamente ingresando dist/main/main.exe
El .spec lo cree previamente para incorporar la carpeta de imágenes que utiliza la aplicación.
No entiendo si el problema está en la creación del propio ejecutable.
Cuando corro el PyInstaller me salen la siguientes líneas:

```
83 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.2
83 INFO: Python: 3.6.8
83 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
86 INFO: wrote E:\Informatica\Proyecto Juego Cervantes\main.spec
87 INFO: UPX is not available.
92 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['E:\\Informatica\\Proyecto Juego Cervantes',
 'E:\\Informatica\\Proyecto Juego Cervantes']
113 INFO: checking Analysis
113 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
113 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
117 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
139 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.
147 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3392 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
3498 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3527 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\ivo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
3625 INFO: Analyzing E:\Informatica\Proyecto Juego Cervantes\main.py
4431 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
4432 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
5877 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.   
5883 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib'
8642 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
15317 INFO: Processing module hooks...
15318 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
15320 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-reportlab.lib.utils.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
15328 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-reportlab.pdfbase._fontdata.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...     
15725 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32ctypes.core.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
15973 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
15976 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module difflib
15977 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
15978 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
15982 INFO: Excluding import of lib2to3.refactor from module distutils.util
15983 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16098 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16102 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module heapq
16103 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16106 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16192 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16194 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'test'
16194 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.core.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16374 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16376 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16382 INFO: Excluding import of pytest from module numpy._pytesttester
16383 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16401 INFO: Excluding import of argparse from module pickle
16402 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16787 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16791 INFO: Excluding import of numpy from module PIL.ImageFilter
16791 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16799 INFO: Excluding import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
16800 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
16804 INFO: Excluding import of PyQt5 from module PIL.ImageQt
16806 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16810 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
16810 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
17320 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
17980 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
17981 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
17986 INFO: Excluding import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
17987 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18025 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18794 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py33compat from module setuptools.depends
18796 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py33compat from module setuptools.package_index
18802 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py27compat from module setuptools.command.easy_install       
18802 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py27compat from module setuptools.package_index
18804 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18826 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18828 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18829 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18831 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
19085 INFO: checking Tree
19086 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
19086 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
19187 INFO: checking Tree
19187 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
19188 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
19326 INFO: checking Tree
19326 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
19326 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
19335 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
19836 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
20728 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
21297 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
21301 INFO: Excluding import of numpy from module setuptools.msvc
21356 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
21411 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
21421 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
21433 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
21451 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
21468 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32api.py'
21469 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
21485 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
22164 INFO: Looking for eggs
22164 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\ivo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
22165 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
22177 INFO: Warnings written to E:\Informatica\Proyecto Juego Cervantes\build\main\warn-main.txt        
22337 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to E:\Informatica\Proyecto Juego Cervantes\build\main\xref-main.html
22398 INFO: checking PYZ
22399 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
22399 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) E:\Informatica\Proyecto Juego Cervantes\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz    
23921 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) E:\Informatica\Proyecto Juego Cervantes\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
23946 INFO: checking PKG
23947 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
23948 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
24010 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
24012 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\ivo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
24012 INFO: checking EXE
24013 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
24013 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
24016 INFO: Copying icons from ['c:\\users\\ivo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
24033 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
24033 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
24034 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
24034 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
24034 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
24035 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
24035 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
24035 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
24041 INFO: Appending archive to EXE E:\Informatica\Proyecto Juego Cervantes\build\main\main.exe        
24074 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
24081 INFO: checking COLLECT
24082 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
24083 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
27865 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

No sé si me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Tenía un problema similar, en mi caso resulto que tenía instaladas las librerías en un entorno virtual, pero cuando se creaba el archivo ejecutable, no tomaba las librerías del entorno virtual, si no de las instaladas en el PC. Lo que hice fue instalar las librerías que estaba usando directamente en el PC. Espero les pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

haciendo:

```
pyinstaller -F nombre.py
```

(-F = onefile) me creo solo el .exe, comprimiendo todos los archivos allí. Luego copié ese archivo en la carpeta raiz del main.py y ahí funcionó
Debe haber una forma mejor, pero ahora ejecuta

Era un problema de jerarquía de carpetas en windows.

Este hilo puede cerrarse